# Can you create new accounts via Adwords API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'd like to create a service which allows ours clients to sign up themselves and set up their own campaigns. Using the AdWords API is is possible to create AdWords accounts dynamically and then manage them through the API? Or is this option only available to resellers? (example, a business we know wants to sign up, they sign up on our app and in the background a new AdWords account is created that belongs to our Adwords Client Centre).

From my research it seems that this is not possible and, instead, we would need to run our own account and add each client's campaign as a separate campaign under our account?

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Google recently added support for creating accounts using the AdWords API. See http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/discover-adwords-v201109.html for details.

Cheers,
Anash

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here's an [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201509/AccountManagement/CreateAccount.php). But you still have to log in and update billing information. Still looking for a way to use current billing info and simply assign it to new account.